# Cross account access for AWS accounts using Direct Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have been working with AWS for a number of years, but I am not very strong with some of the advanced networking concepts.

So, we have multiple AWS accounts. None of them have public internet access, but we use Direct Connect for on-prem to AWS connection.

I have a S3 bucket in Account A. 
I created an IAM user in Account A along with a access/secret key and granted this IAM user s3:PutObject permission to the S3 bucket.

I write a simple Python script to list the objects in this bucket from on-prem, it works, as expected.

I then execute the same Python script on an EC2 instance running in Account B, I get *"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occured (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied".*

Do I need to create VPC endpoint for S3 in Account B? Does cross account IAM role come into play here?

Comment: What credentials are you using in Account B? If you are using the permissions from the EC2 instance then you'll need to assume a cross account role that has the permissions you need. Technically, you could use the access/secret key created in Account A from the EC2 instance in Account B, but that would not be recommended. If you have a bucket policy on the bucket that restricts access unless you are inside the VPC then things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I am not using EC2 instance role in Account B. I am using a access/secret key that belongs to an IAM user in Account A. With this setup, I get access denied. And there is no bucket policy on the bucket that restricts access unless you are inside the VPC.

Comment: Do you have your bucket policy set to block public access?

Comment: Let me check with our AWS guys. What affect does this have?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access.html. The one that is likely your issue is this one "Only authorized users of this account – Access is isolated to IAM users and roles in this account and AWS service principals because there is a policy that grants public access."

Comment: To be clear, you should leave that on. The better solution is to assume a role across accounts and use the role in Account A to access a bucket in Account A.

Comment: Using role across accounts make sense. I will try that out.

Comment: So, just to be clear, if Account B (with the EC2 instance) had an internet gateway attached to it, I could simply write to the S3 bucket in Account A without having to deal with role across accounts, correct?

Comment: Since you are using credentials from Account A, yes, assuming you don't have a bucket policy that restricts access to a particular VPC.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is:

- You have an Amazon S3 `Bucket-A` in `Account-A`
- You have an IAM User (`User-A`) in `Account-A`
- You have an Amazon EC2 instance running in `Account-B`
- From that EC2 instance, you wish to access `Bucket-A`
- It also appears that you have a means for the EC2 instance to access Amazon S3 endpoints to make API calls

Assuming that the instance is able to reach Amazon S3 (which appears to be true because the error message refers to permissions, which would have come from S3), there are two ways to authenticate for access to `Bucket-A`:

**Option 1: Using the IAM User from Account-A**

When making the call from the EC2 instance to `Bucket-A`, use the IAM credentials created in Bucket-A. It doesn't matter that the request is coming from an Amazon EC2 instance in `Account-B`. In fact, Amazon S3 doesn't even know that. An API call can come from *anywhere on the Internet* (including your home computer or mobile phone). What matters is the set of credentials provided when making the call.

If you are using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to make the call, then you can save the `User-A` credentials as a profile by using `aws configure --profile user_a` (or any name), then entering the credentials from the IAM User in `Account-A`. Then, access Amazon S3 with `aws s3 ls --profile user_a`. Using a profile like this allows you to switch between credentials.

**Option 2: Using a Bucket Policy**

Amazon S3 also has the ability to specify a Bucket Policy on a bucket, which can grant access to the bucket. So, if the EC2 instance is using credentials from `Account-B`, you can add a Bucket Policy that grants access from those `Account-B` credentials.

Let's say that the Amazon EC2 instance was launched with an IAM Role called `role-b`, then you could use a Bucket Policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-B>:role/role-b"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Disclaimer:** All of the above assumes that you don't have any weird policies on your VPC Endpoints / Amazon S3 Access Points or however the VPCs are connecting with the Amazon S3 endpoints.

Comment: So, here is why I am still confused.
When I run the above Python script from an on-prem machine, I can connect.

I try to run the exact same script (using the same access/secret keys) from an EC2 instance in Account-B, I get Access Denied.

Again, to reiterate, both Accounts A and B don't have an IGW. They use a Direct Connect connection.

I will need to review VPC endpoints, S3 Access Points, etc.

Comment: Internet Gateways are attached to **VPCs**, not accounts. Are you able to use the AWS CLI from the EC2 instance, using those credentials? If so, try `aws s3 ls` and see whether the desired bucket appears in the list. This will indicate whether the credentials being used are associated with the AWS Account you are expecting.

Comment: We were able to trace the issue to a weird policy on the VPC Endpoint.